# Sending JSON files in a system2 command in R?

Tags: json, r

I am trying to call python from R, by using a system2 command. I am trying to convert a dataframe in R to a JSON format, and then pass it via the system2 command.

For a trivial example, given dataframe df:

```
A  B  C 
1  2  3 
4  5  6
```

Then, using 'jsonlite' I convert 'df' to a json format.

```
df_converted = jsonlite::toJSON(df)
```

I then want to use a simple system2 command.

```
path_to_script  = "C:/myscript.py"
allArgs = c(path_to_script, df_converted)
system2('python', args = allArgs, stdout=TRUE)
```

Since I am asking an R question, I don't feel like it is appropriate to include the python code, but it is irrelevant anyway.

i think the issue may be that I can't include an argument that has embedded quotes, which would be a simple(ish) fix for small dataframes, but not at all for large. So my question, is there any way to send JSON files as an argument in this system2 command without just removing all of the quotes?

Comment: Depending on the size of the dataframe, you may prefer to save it to disk and read it in in your python script. Options for this include CSV and (some may argue faster) [`feather`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/feather/index.html) ([python module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feather-format)).

Answer (score 0):

If we make a `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 | jq '.'
```

and put it `/tmp` (i.e. `/tmp/example.sh`), and then do:

```
library(jsonlite)

df <- read.table(text="A  B  C 
1  2  3
4  5  6", header=TRUE) 

system2("/tmp/example.sh", shQuote(toJSON(df)))
```

we get this in the R console:

```
[
  {
    "A": 1,
    "B": 2,
    "C": 3
  },
  {
    "A": 4,
    "B": 5,
    "C": 6
  }
]
```

You have the misfortune of needing to use Python, so we'll also put:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from sys import argv
import json

param = json.loads(argv[1])

print(json.dumps(param, indent=4)) # larger indent than jq's default
```

in `/tmp/example.py` and change the line in the R script to:

```
system2("/tmp/example.py", shQuote(toJSON(df)))
```

and get:

```
[
    {
        "A": 1,
        "B": 2,
        "C": 3
    },
    {
        "A": 4,
        "B": 5,
        "C": 6
    }
]
```

in the R console, so the JSON is passed in correctly.

I agree with @r2evans that if you have a decent chunk of JSON and can modify the script you need to call, it may be better (in the long run) to save the JSON to a temp file and read it from a temp file.